# Unable to change the objects key value using lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

```
var flagsObj = {
  logical1Flag: false,
  operator1Flag: false,
  resourceLeftFlag: false,
  resource1Flag: false,
  resourceRightFlag: false,
};
```

in the object above i wanted to change the value of any one of them and make it to true and the rest i wanted to make it to false. i have used this function which is mentioned below, however i am able to change the value of the using the map values or foreach function but the original flagsobj is not getting changes.

```
function settingFlag(val, keyF) { 
   const trueVal = val;
   const falseVal = false;
   const assignedKey = keyF;

_.mapValues(this.flagsObj, (value, key) => {
  if (key === assignedKey) {
    value = true;
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  // console.log(value);
  console.log(`
    Flags
    ====
    key ${key} value ${value}
  `);
});
```

or using the forEach to manipulate the data

```
_.forEach(this.flagsObj, (value, key) => {
  if (key === assignedKey) {
    value = true;
    console.log(`
    flags
    =====
    key ${key} value ${value}
    `);
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
});
console.log('::::: FLAGS :::: ', flagsObj);
}
```

both foreach or map values  are changing the required values the but the original flagsObj is not getting changed.

any lodash function which would solve the problem is appreciated. i am using angular 1.5 es6 application

Comment: `mapValues` returns a new object. Something like `let result = _.mapValues(this.flagsObj, (v, k) => key === assignedKey)` will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about lodash, but a one liner in plain js will do it

```js
var flagsObj = {
  logical1Flag: false,
  operator1Flag: false,
  resourceLeftFlag: false,
  resource1Flag: false,
  resourceRightFlag: false,
};

function change(obj, key) {
  return Object.keys(obj).forEach(v => obj[v] = v === key);
}

change(flagsObj, "logical1Flag");

console.log(flagsObj);
```

Comment: Thanks Baao , it works. but simultaneously i wanted to set the rest of the key value to false. like setting logical1Flag to true , should set the operator1Flag, resourceLeftFlag, resource1Flag, resourceRightFlag to false , similarly if i call change(flagsObj, "logical1flag") which sets to logical1flag to true and then i call change(flagsObj, "resource1flag"), we will have logical1Flag and resource1Flag. to true. But still it works, if you edit the answer to meet this would be great

Comment: Changed it @user2180800

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to store the original `flagsObj` as a constant or reset object that you can use to restore the `false` of all flags. Assign this to the `flagsObj`, make sure to clone it using [`lodash#clone`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone) to avoid mutating the `ORIGINAL_FLAG_OBJECT` variable. Next is to create a function that accepts a flag that we set to true; we accomplish this by using [`lodash#assign`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) to assign all values from the `ORIGINAL_FLAG_OBJECT` to the `flagsObj` to modify all flags to false, and then use [`lodash#set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) to set that particular `flag` key to true.

```js
var ORIGINAL_FLAG_OBJECT = {
  logical1Flag: false,
  operator1Flag: false,
  resourceLeftFlag: false,
  resource1Flag: false,
  resourceRightFlag: false,
};

var flagsObj = _.clone(ORIGINAL_FLAG_OBJECT);

function activateFlag(flag) {
  return _(flagsObj)
    .assign(ORIGINAL_FLAG_OBJECT)
    .set(flag, true)
    .value();
}

console.log(activateFlag('resourceRightFlag'));
console.log(activateFlag('resource1Flag'));
console.log(activateFlag('resourceLeftFlag'));
console.log(activateFlag('operator1Flag'));
console.log(activateFlag('logical1Flag'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it:

```
function settingFlag(val, keyF) { 
   const trueVal = val;
   const falseVal = false;
   const assignedKey = keyF;

  return _.mapValues(this.flagsObj, (value, key) => {
    if (key === assignedKey) {
      value = true;
    } else {
      value = false;
    }
    return value;
  });
}
```

According to [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues):

> Returns the new mapped array.

It doesn't mutate the original one.

With you `_.forEach` one, first off, you should only use it on an array (you're using it on an object). It might technically work, and for the sake of argument, even if you do use `forEach`, setting `value = true` only sets a variable, not the property of an object. You'd need to do `this.flagsObject[key] = // true or false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the keys of object using a simple for and set the value to the key that matches with the one specified, and false otherwise:

```js
var flagsObj = {
  logical1Flag: false,
  operator1Flag: false,
  resourceLeftFlag: false,
  resource1Flag: false,
  resourceRightFlag: false,
};

function settingFlag(val, keyF) {
  for (var key in flagsObj) {
    flagsObj[key] = (key === keyF) ? val : false;
  }
}

settingFlag(true, 'operator1Flag');

console.log(flagsObj);
```

Comment: @user2180800 Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, there might be an easier way. If only one of the flags can be true at a time, and you're just trying to set which one;

```
this.flags = ['logical1', 'operator1', 'resourceLeft', 'resource1', 'resourceRight'];
this.currentFlag = -1;
```

then, to set the current flag, do `this.currentFlag = this.flags.findIndex(a => a === keyF)`, and to get the currently set flag, do `this.flags[this.currentFlag]`. This is more efficient than iterating the object each time, and stays nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Easy; use the `obj` param of `forEach`

```
_.forEach(this.flagsObj, (value, key, obj) => {
  obj[key] = key === assignedKey
});
```